# SAP IDoc missing file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, idoc

I am integrating a BizTalk application with SAP system. I get an error when SAP sends me IDoc data because the required schema is not declared in BizTalk.

The required schema is `http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZCREMAS01//700`.

I can find this schema in SAP (when consuming an adapter service from BizTalk), but it does not contain the segment `E2LFM1M005`.

The error I get is

> The adapter "WCF-Custom" raised an error message. Details
> "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderGenerationException:
> The segment or group definition E2LFM1M005 was not found in the IDoc
> metadata. The UniqueId of the IDoc type is: IDOCTYP/3/ZCREMAS01//700.
> For Receive operations, the SAP adapter does not support unreleased
> segments.

Can you tell me where can I find this IDoc definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAP release when it comes to idocs can be a bit tricky. In your case, your SAP system will probably be in a higher version then 700.
There are 2 things that you can change.

1. In your SAP receive location, go to the "Binding" tab in the settings and check the "ReceiveIdocRelease" parameter. There should be a syntax hint on the bottom.
2. In SAP go to WE20 and check the specific LS, KU, ... you are using. If you edit the idoc type you want to change there, you can see on the bottom a field where you can specify a segment release. Put 700 here and try again.

I can't really make screenshots now. If it's not clear, let me know. I'll post a more complete answer next week.

Kind Regards
Tim

Comment: thanks for the update. After much testing and the help of a SAP engineer, we found that the parameter PI_APPLREL required a certain value (not sure which). Our SAP engineer fixed it and everything worked fine.